# In Kotlin, how can you tell if ":" means extends or returns?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Java is a bit more explicit on this, but is there a rule of thumb for when learning Kotlin to know when `:` indicates that it is returning something, vs when it is extending a class?

Example:

```
data class SlothGeneric(
    val slothName: String,
    val isTwoFingered: Boolean,
    var slothWeight: Int
): Mammal(slothName)
```

How do we know if this class `SlothGeneric` is returning a `Mammal` class, or if it is extending it?

Comment: It means "of type", as in "data class SlothGeneric of type Mammal", "function sin of type Double", "value sloth of type SlothGeneric", etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Classes can't return anything (only their functions can), so when you see the colon `:` on a class definition, it means `extends` / `implements`.

Functions on the other hand can't extent or implement anything, but can have a return type, so the colon `:` indicates the return type in a function definition.

Comment: At quick glance, when looking at classes, parenthesis '()' means extends (inheritance) and no parenthesis means implements (interfaces). Functions never have parenthesis on their return type.

Comment: This answer should be edited to read "the colon" in both instances of "the semicolon`. It won't let me edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the code follows the default Kotlin coding style, the difference between extending type and specifying the type of a declaration can be told by spaces around colon:

- if `:` separates a declaration (a property or a function) from its type, there should be no space before `:`

  ```
  fun Mammal.giveBirth(): Mammal
  ```
- if `:` separates a type from its supertype, `:` should have a space before

  ```
  class Sloth : Mammal
  ```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#colon